# @BeforeAdvise is not working for same method names in Spring BOOT

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop

I am learning Spring AOP and tried to call the @BeforeAdvise for two Different methods in different classes. But the log added in the first call is getting printed only. Please check the code below and let me know what is not correct here.

**MainClass**

```
package com.example.aspects;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import com.example.aspects.AopClasses.DemoConfig;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AspectsApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AspectsApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**AspectClass**

```
package com.example.aspects.Acpects;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class MyLoggingDemo {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyLoggingDemo.class);

    @Before("execution(public String test())")
    public void beforeCheck() {
        logger.info("Before Check !!!!!!!!!!!! "+System.currentTimeMillis() );  
    }   
}
```

**ConfigClass**

```
package com.example.aspects.AopClasses;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan("com.example.aspects")
public class DemoConfig {

}
```

**TestClass- Where the first call is made to the function**

```
package com.example.aspects.AopClasses;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class tesTClass {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(tesTClass.class);
     MemberShipDAO dao = new MemberShipDAO();

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String test() {
        logger.info("Hey I am here");
        return "HEy There I am Working !!";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value ="/test")
    public String testing() {
        logger.info("MemberShipDAO Call");
    return  dao.test();     // method with same name called here again
    }   
}
```

**MemberShipDAO - Declared the test method again here**

```
package com.example.aspects.AopClasses;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MemberShipDAO {

    public String test() {
        return "HEy!!";
    }
}
```

**Console**

```
2022-01-18 11:37:52.794  INFO 8032 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-01-18 11:37:52.796  INFO 8032 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-01-18 11:37:52.802  INFO 8032 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 5 ms
2022-01-18 11:37:52.811  INFO 8032 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.example.aspects.Acpects.MyLoggingDemo  : Before Check !!!!!!!!!!!! 1642486072811
2022-01-18 11:37:52.854  INFO 8032 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.example.aspects.AopClasses.tesTClass   : Hey I am here
2022-01-18 11:37:57.383  INFO 8032 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.example.aspects.AopClasses.tesTClass   : MemberShipDAO Call
```

Comment: `MembershipDAO` isn't managed by Spring, you are creating an instance yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
MemberShipDAO dao = new MemberShipDAO();
```

to this

```
@Autowired MemberShipDAO dao;
```

Spring's magic for the AOP happens only when you use the instance created by Spring. Behind the scene, Spring instantiated your dao and wrapped it with a [proxy](https://www.baeldung.com/cglib) that makes a call to your aspect.